# Texture is showing artifact (bottom wraps to top) when using transparency in Godot

Tags: 3d, textures, godot

When I add a png with transparency as the texture for a plane, I get these artifacts where the pixels wrap around to the opposite edge. Here, the bottom edge has non transparent pixels, so the top edge is showing some of the pixels wrapped around. Is there a way to get rid of this?

I'm using Godot 3.4.4, GLES2.

[image: grass texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are telling me is that the texture is imported to repeat and you do not want that. Double check how you imported the texture: With the texture file selected in the File System panel, go to the import panel (if you changed them, you need to click "reimport"). And flags the texture resource has in the Inspector panel.